# bootstrap table Column options formatter function can not found the function in the component?

Tags: typescript, this, angular-cli, bootstrap-table

I have write a component use angular4  in angular cli project.Then i use bootstrap-table(http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/)
in this component .
The code is like this:

```js
import { ***  } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-template',
  templateUrl: './template.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./template.component.less']
})
export class TemplateComponent implements OnInit , OnDestroy  {

   constructor() {
    const that = this;//the point is here
    that.showMessage('message');// run  correct ,can use that
  }
    columnDefs : any[] = [//defined the table column
    {
      checkbox: true
    },
    {
      title: this.translate.instant('template.template'),
      field: 'name',
      width: 200,
      sortable: true,
      events: 'operateEvents',
      formatter:  (value : any, row : any, index : any) =>  {
        that.showMessage(value);/// the point is here  ,// run  error ,can not use that    
      }
    }]

    gridOptions : {} = {//defined the table 
    pagination: true,
    escape: true,
    pageSize: 10,
    pageList: [10, 25, 50, 100],
    search: true,
    strictSearch: false,
    searchText: '',
    paginationDetailHAlign: 'left',
    paginationHAlign: 'left',
    clickToSelect: false,
    sortable: true,
    toolbar: '#toolbar-template-toolbar',
  };
  
  

 
  showMessage(value:any) {
     console.log('this.is a message ',value);
  } 
  ngOnInit() {
     $('#table-template').bootstrapTable($.extend(this.gridOptions, {
      columns: that.columnDefs,
      data: [],
    }));
  }
  

}
```

but  the angular cli show error like this :

ERROR in /root/code/***/src/app/template/template.component.ts (106,9): Cannot find name 'that'.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvQkf.png)

The context (this) is the column Object. So to access showMessage ,i must use that ..
but why ?????  why the error occur ???  thanks  for your help !!!!

Comment: What you are trying to do here with "that". You can use this in place of this.

Comment: @Subbu  the bootstrap table document said  the formatter function ,The context (this) is the column Object. 
The cell formatter function, take three parameters: 
value: the field value. 
row: the row record data.
index: the row index.   It means  that 'this' in the formatter function is pointer to column object  not the 'this'  in the global

Answer (score 0):

"that" variable is local scope to constructor. Hence you are getting "cannot find" where you referred it. To resolve your issue, don't use "that" variable approach. get columnDefs values get assigned into local variable and use it inside jQuery methods.

```
ngOnInit() {
     let columDefs= this.columnDefs; //assign into local var
     let girdOpt = this.gridOptions; //assign into local var
     $('#table-template').bootstrapTable($.extend(girdOpt, {
      columns: columnDefs, //Use here
      data: [],
    }));
  }
```